# CSS morphing word/text

Tags: css, animation, text

Is there a way to morph the text for a title from one word to another while retaining the letters used in both words? Many of the css text animations I have looked at are mostly visual and there are the few that rotate whole words.

What I am looking to do is transition from a word, e.g. "BEACH" to "CHANGE" where some letters will disappear and others will rearrange.

I know it can be done in After Effects and can sort of be done using spin/keyframes  but it is not smooth and quite janky.

Any help or if there are similar projects that could be implemented would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I made a sample for you, maybe not exactly what you need, but you can improve from here: https://jsfiddle.net/0gkt8qw6/4/

The way I'm doing it is to treat each letter as one element, like so

### HTML

```
<div class="word first-form">
  <div class="letter letter-b">B</div>
  <div class="letter letter-c">C</div>
  <div class="letter letter-h">H</div>
  <div class="letter letter-a">A</div>
  <div class="letter letter-n">N</div>
  <div class="letter letter-g">G</div>
  <div class="letter letter-e">E</div>
</div>
```

Then I'm moving each of the character using transform: translateX(). Note that I made each letter to have the same width, i.e. 58px. This allows me to animate the translate using percentage. Keep in mind about this if you're using special kind of font.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

here's another sample for you which involves a few javascript
http://jsfiddle.net/29wtdj0e/12/

just change the values inside the `letsgo('BEACH','CHANGE')` function.

it has 2 loops, 1 for the each word. the first loop creates new elements for letters not in the 1st word, and animates it. first loop also checks for existing letters and animate them directly.

2nd loop just hides letters from the first word that are not needed.